# Transition probabilities in Continuous Time Markov Chain following Poisson Processes

Tags: matlab, statistics, markov-chains, markov

Let's imagine we have the following states corresponding to the number of users in a system in a Continuous Time Markov Chain:

---- [10]  ------ [11] ------ [12] ........... [17]

The arrival of a new users in the system follows a Poisson distribution at rate \lambda, and service time (users leave the system) at rate \mu.
I want to compute the probability that staying at state [10] jumps into state [17]. That is, the probability that having 10 users in the system, 7 more users arrive in the system.
It is possible to compute?

I tried the s-transform method that use first derivative but I'm unable to compute it.

```
lambda_ = 1

# Service rate (Poisson parameter)
mu = 1/60 

# Define the rate matrix Q
Q = np.array([[-lambda_, lambda_],
              [mu, -mu]])

# Compute the stationary distribution π
pi = np.linalg.solve(Q.T.dot(np.eye(2)), np.ones(2))
pi /= np.sum(pi)

# Initial state distribution
p0 = np.array([0.6, 0.4])  # Example initial state distribution

# Time points
t = 1.0  # Example time point

# Compute transient probabilities
pt = p0.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(np.exp(Q * t), 1))

print("Transient probabilities at time t:", pt)
```

Comment: You tagged both [tag:r] and [tag:matlab], please clarify which of the two languages you're intending to use, plus any non-base packages/libraries you're intending to use (is there a function for the s-transform method?). Also, please include the code you've attempted so far, and if needed sample data to use it on. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I tried the s-transform method in Python but the result is wrong. \lambda = Exp(60), \mu = Exp(1/60). Exp(rate) is the exponential distribution.

Comment: Are you wanting the probability this happens in one transition (in the embedded discrete time markov chain)?  Or in a fixed amount of time? A CTMC of this kind does not go from state 10 to state 17 directly.

Comment: Exactly, in the first case.